# keep value in textbox after page reload to itself in php?

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, onchange, retain

I have two textboxes and two dropdowns in a form. After filling values in textboxes and selecting value from dropdown the page reloads and based on value selected in dropdown other dropdown gets populated. But values in textboxes is not there. How to retain these textboxes values.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form action="selectmultiplepost.php" method="post" name="myform">

First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br>


Industry Name <select name="industryid" id="industrySelect" onchange="document.location.href = 'selectmultiple.php?industryid=' + this.value">
<option>SELECT</option>
<?php
include('config.php');

$query = "select IndustryId, IndustryName from industrytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fetch['IndustryId'];?>"><?php echo $fetch['IndustryName'];?></option>
        <?php
    }
}


?>
</select><br>
Skills <select name="skillname">
<option>SELECT</option>
<?php
include('config.php');

if(isset($_GET['industryid']))
{
$industryID = $_GET['industryid'];
}
else
{
$industryID = "";
}

$skillQuery = "select SkillId, SkillName from skilltable where Industryid='".$industryID."'";
$resultSkill = mysql_query($skillQuery);
if(mysql_num_rows($resultSkill) > 0)
{
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($resultSkill))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fetch['SkillId'];?>"><?php echo $fetch['SkillName'];?></option>
        <?php
    }
}

?>

</select><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitform" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script>

document.getElementById('industrySelect').value = "<?php echo $_GET['industryid'];?>";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think you need to understand some basics about how things work, so I am going to ignore the fact you are using the mysql_* extension which you should no longer use as it has been deprecated.

Ok so the first thing to rememebr is that a php script/page will get executed from top to bottom every time you a) launch the page from the browser and/or b) Press a submit button.

With regard to your actual question, that means is that the 2 lines of your form that create the `First Name` and `Last Name` input fields will get run as you code them on each execution.

So if you want to re-load what was entered by the user, you have to do it yourself, I am afraid its not done by magic.

```
<form action="selectmultiplepost.php" method="post" name="myform">

First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br>
```

So you will need to check if the user entered anything, just like you are doing for the `industryid` later in the page and if so put that value in the the `value=""` property. Something like this

```
<?php
    $fn = !empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
    $ln = !empty($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
?>
    First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $fn;?>"><br>
    Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $ln;?>"><br>
```

I also notice that the later code is using `$_GET` but your `<form` tag is telling the browser to use `method="post"` so you should be using the $_POST array and not the $_GET array all the way through your code.

*I also see lots of other errors in your code, but as they are not the subject of your question I will leave those for you to ask other questions about*

Comment: thank you sir, i really appreciate your help but it still does not work. The text fields are empty after page refresh. But with ajax it is working

Comment: Do they get filled with what the user entered when you press the Submit button? Not quite sure what you mean by _after page refresh_

Comment: No. On pressing submit button the page is redirected to server side script say xyz.php. After filling text inputs when I select an industry from industry dropdown a request is sent to a php script on server(here page refreshes) which returns the array of skills corresponding to that industry. Now after this visit to server the values I enter in text fields arer no longer their.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way is like this :

```html
<form action="selectmultiplepost.php" method="post" name="myform">  
First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){
echo $_POST['firstname'];} ?>">

<br>
Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){
echo $_POST['lastname'];} ?>">

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<br>

<input type="submit" name="submitform" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

and for SQL queries use PDO class for security stuff,by the way!

Answer (score -1):

put like this,

```
First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value=isset($_GET['firstname'])? $_GET['firstname']:""><br>

Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" value=isset($_GET['lastname'])? $_GET['lastname'] :""><br>
```

Comment: why we are using $_GET here?

Comment: to set the value after submit

Comment: I am not submitting the form, rather page is reloading on changing the dropdown value so that second dropdown gets populated. Also the form method is post.